# Conversion from Teradata to Snowflake SQL

Tags: type-conversion, teradata, reset, partition, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having difficulty in converting a Partition code from Teradata to Snowflake.The Partition code has reset function in it. May i know how to Snowflake

```
SUM(1) OVER (PARTITION BY acct_id ORDER BY  snap_dt RESET WHEN reset_flag = 1 ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite it using two nested functions:

```
SELECT ...
    ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER (PARTITION BY acct_id, new_part -- add new_part to the existing partition  
          ORDER BY snap_dt
          ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM
     (
       SELECT -- returns the same value for all rows within a group
          SUM(CASE WHEN reset_flag = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
          OVER (PARTITION BY acct_id 
                ORDER BY snap_dt
                ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS new_part
       ...
     ) AS dt
```